# IFRAME makes src servlet execute twice on ipad safari

Tags: html, ipad, jakarta-ee, servlets, iframe

I have an `iframe` which gets its content from a `servlet`. The problem is that the `servlet` doGet method gets executed twice when the page of the `iframe` is loaded. Here is the html:

```
<div style="position: absolute;top: 135px;left:0px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:scroll;width: 975px;height: 873px;" align="center">
    <iframe src="documentviewer?docid=#{viewIncomingBean.connectedAttachment.id}" width="630px" height="873px" style="border: 1px solid black;"></iframe>
</div>
```

this problem only show up when i run the application on `ipad` safari, it works fine on firefox

Is there any way to prevent the double execution of the `servlet`?

Comment: I don't think it will be executed twice. If you can show the complete page HTML, then a solution can be provided.

Comment: <ice:panelGroup  rendered="#{viewInternalMemoBean.docFlag}">
<div style="position: absolute;top: 135px;left:0px;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:scroll;width: 975px;height: 873px;" align="center">
<iframe src="documentviewer?docid=#{viewInternalMemoBean.internalMemo.id}" width="630px" height="873px" style="border: 1px solid black;">
</iframe> 
</div></ice:panelGroup>

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem that it is hitting your doGet method twice legitimately? There are 2 page requests here, 1 for the page and 1 for the IFRAME.

If I am misunderstanding what is wrong, let me know.

Comment: after adding a special parameter in parameter string in the *'iframe'* to the *'servlet'* request i made sure that the 2 requests came from the same *'iframe'*, after the 2 requests complete the *'onload'* event of the *'iframe'* executed

Comment: the load event of the **iframe** is executed just one time

Comment: i discovered that the servlet execute twice when i reun the application on apple ipad safari, it works fine on firefox on my PC

Comment: I see. This is a strange issue. I was going to suggest something *somewhere* in your code was causing it but it seems to be browser specific. Can you duplicate this double request bug with a very basic version of your `IFRAME` code?